# How to install Biopython on windows7?

Tags: installation, windows-7, bioinformatics, biopython

I am getting error:

> > > pip install biopython
> > >       SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to install biopython within the Python [REPL](https://codewith.mu/en/tutorials/1.0/repl). See my screenshot below if that looks like what you are getting. Type `quit()` to exit the Python REPL and type `pip install biopython` on the commandline:

[image]

Comment: I have installed python 3.8, now I want to install bio-python when I am typing python on command prompt it is showing "Python is not recognized external or internal command" but I am working fine in IDLE of python. Kindly resolve the issue.

Comment: That error means that you will have to modify a setting called PATH so that your computer knows where to find the Python interpreter. See https://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows.html#id2 or https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#from-the-command-line

Answer (score 0):

Did you go to the pip folder? On Windows, by default python and pip are not on the PATH.

Please go to the windows section of the [Biopython installation](https://biopython.org/wiki/Download) tutorial.

It says you should be able to install if you run it from the pip folder.